# Make QVBoxLayout scrollable inside a QScrollArea

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qscrollarea, qlayout, qvboxlayout

I have a QVBoxLayout which has content dynamically added to it. I simply want to make that layout scrollable as the content overflows.

What is the correct way to achieve this in Qt Designer, or do I need code as well?

Answer (score 1):

In Qt Designer:

- Create a QScrollArea
- Drag your existing QVBoxLayout into the QScrollArea.
- Right-click inside the QScrollArea (not inside the layout), and select "Apply Layout".
- Choose a layout (I chose a vertical layout).